# How to resolve the issue "Corda service net.corda.finance.internal.ConfigHolder does not exist" with corda finance app?

Tags: java, corda

I have setup an [AWS Corda node connected to the Corda Testnet](https://docs.corda.net/aws-vm-explore.html), with finance app running. When trying to use the [Node Explorer](https://docs.corda.net/testnet-explorer-corda.html), an error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Corda service net.corda.finance.internal.ConfigHolder does not exist" is encountered.

Tested with Corda finance app version 4.0 and 4.1 to no avail.

````
[INFO ] 2019-09-21T06:19:54,305Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow.run - Flow raised an error... sending it to flow hospital {actor_id=cordazoneservice, actor_owning_identity=OU=C43865825-62f1-4389-b97e-12342b9783c5, O=DBS, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=f123044c-d448-445f-9288-25c0d5d0b9ca, invocation_id=ccdf5ca0-b0ee-4619-b21a-f06c4d58c8bc, invocation_timestamp=2019-09-21T06:19:54.115Z, origin=cordazoneservice, session_id=91340576-8889-429c-8ae4-2622e6e5d129, session_timestamp=2019-09-21T06:19:47.777Z, thread-id=114}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Corda service net.corda.finance.internal.ConfigHolder does not exist
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.cordaService(AbstractNode.kt:985) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.finance.internal.CashConfigDataFlow.call(CashConfigDataFlow.kt:47) ~[corda-finance-workflows-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.finance.internal.CashConfigDataFlow.call(CashConfigDataFlow.kt:44) ~[corda-finance-workflows-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:228) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:45) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
[INFO ] 2019-09-21T06:19:54,320Z [Node thread-1] statemachine.StaffedFlowHospital.flowErrored - Flow [f123044c-d448-445f-9288-25c0d5d0b9ca] admitted to hospital in state StateMachineState(checkpoint=Checkpoint(invocationContext=InvocationContext(origin=RPC(actor=Actor(id=Id(value=cordazoneservice), serviceId=AuthServiceId(value=NODE_CONFIG), owningLegalIdentity=OU=C43865825-62f1-4389-b97e-12342b9783c5, O=DBS, L=London, C=GB)), trace=Trace(invocationId=ccdf5ca0-b0ee-4619-b21a-f06c4d58c8bc, timestamp: 2019-09-21T06:19:54.115Z, entityType: Invocation, sessionId=91340576-8889-429c-8ae4-2622e6e5d129, timestamp: 2019-09-21T06:19:47.777Z, entityType: Session), actor=Actor(id=Id(value=cordazoneservice), serviceId=AuthServiceId(value=NODE_CONFIG), owningLegalIdentity=OU=C43865825-62f1-4389-b97e-12342b9783c5, O=DBS, L=London, C=GB), externalTrace=null, impersonatedActor=null), ourIdentity=OU=C43865825-62f1-4389-b97e-12342b9783c5, O=DBS, L=London, C=GB, sessions={}, subFlowStack=[Inlined(flowClass=class net.corda.finance.internal.CashConfigDataFlow, subFlowVersion=CoreFlow(platformVersion=4), isEnabledTimedFlow=false)], flowState=Unstarted(flowStart=Explicit, frozenFlowLogic=2E6D42D61FE307CAFC818AC8CB4B43146055B3A5D7B8DC2F699D10C2458F35BF), errorState=Clean, numberOfSuspends=0), flowLogic=net.corda.finance.internal.CashConfigDataFlow@1c0a20b9, pendingDeduplicationHandlers=[], isFlowResumed=true, isTransactionTracked=false, isAnyCheckpointPersisted=true, isStartIdempotent=false, isRemoved=false, senderUUID=231bf46f-8ef5-4cff-bf86-98e32e4f096f) {actor_id=cordazoneservice, actor_owning_identity=OU=C43865825-62f1-4389-b97e-12342b9783c5, O=DBS, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=f123044c-d448-445f-9288-25c0d5d0b9ca, invocation_id=ccdf5ca0-b0ee-4619-b21a-f06c4d58c8bc, invocation_timestamp=2019-09-21T06:19:54.115Z, origin=cordazoneservice, session_id=91340576-8889-429c-8ae4-2622e6e5d129, session_timestamp=2019-09-21T06:19:47.777Z, thread-id=114}
[INFO ] 2019-09-21T06:19:54,322Z [Node thread-1] statemachine.StaffedFlowHospital.invoke - Flow [f123044c-d448-445f-9288-25c0d5d0b9ca] has error [0] {actor_id=cordazoneservice, actor_owning_identity=OU=C43865825-62f1-4389-b97e-12342b9783c5, O=DBS, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=f123044c-d448-445f-9288-25c0d5d0b9ca, invocation_id=ccdf5ca0-b0ee-4619-b21a-f06c4d58c8bc, invocation_timestamp=2019-09-21T06:19:54.115Z, origin=cordazoneservice, session_id=91340576-8889-429c-8ae4-2622e6e5d129, session_timestamp=2019-09-21T06:19:47.777Z, thread-id=114}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Corda service net.corda.finance.internal.ConfigHolder does not exist
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.cordaService(AbstractNode.kt:985) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.finance.internal.CashConfigDataFlow.call(CashConfigDataFlow.kt:47) ~[corda-finance-workflows-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.finance.internal.CashConfigDataFlow.call(CashConfigDataFlow.kt:44) ~[corda-finance-workflows-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:228) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:45) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]```
````

Comment: Can you show the startup logs of your node?

Comment: check answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399129/corda-issue-connecting-to-testnet-node-using-tools-explorer/58401638#58401638

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see you figured out the solution to this!

For anyone who doesn't see the comments up there the link to his post where he figured it out is here: [Corda Issue Connecting to TestNet Node Using Tools Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399129/corda-issue-connecting-to-testnet-node-using-tools-explorer/58401638#58401638)

What he did was he added this to his node configuration.

```
"cordappSignerKeyFingerprintBlacklist" : [ ],
```