# Corda Issue Connecting to TestNet Node Using Tools Explorer

Tags: corda

Attempting to connect to a Corda TestNet node following instructions from this link but continue to get below error..

https://docs.corda.net/testnet-explorer-corda.html

`net.corda.nodeapi.exceptions.InternalNodeException: Something went wrong within the Corda node.`

**Node log contents:**

```
[ERROR] 2019-10-15T13:37:48,109Z [Node thread-1] proxies.ExceptionMaskingRpcOpsProxy.log - Error during RPC invocation [errorCode=24h7hj, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/24h7hj] {actor_id=rpcuser, actor_owning_identity=OU=Cb014cf3e-d863-4d6f-827b-6f8813de6b9c, O=TESTNET_Clear Markets, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000003, flow-id=94fd17a4-3a59-4acc-bd50-97220790bcc8, invocation_id=bbd17234-6b67-47ab-83e5-50823956001e, invocation_timestamp=2019-10-15T13:37:48.093Z, origin=rpcuser, session_id=329a00ad-4747-4f9d-b0fd-5b38dcf4ef1e, session_timestamp=2019-10-15T13:37:44.868Z, thread-id=114}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Corda service net.corda.finance.internal.ConfigHolder does not exist
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.cordaService(AbstractNode.kt:985) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.finance.internal.CashConfigDataFlow.call(CashConfigDataFlow.kt:47) ~[corda-finance-workflows-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.finance.internal.CashConfigDataFlow.call(CashConfigDataFlow.kt:44) ~[corda-finance-workflows-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:228) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:45) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
        at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.0.jar:?]
[WARN ] 2019-10-15T13:47:39,383Z [Thread-14] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: syscall:read(..) failed: Connection reset by peer [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
[WARN ] 2019-10-15T13:47:39,404Z [Thread-34 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] rpc.RPCServer.bindingRemovalArtemisMessageHandler - Detected RPC client disconnect on address rpc.client.rpcuser.6152356516528416918, scheduling for reaping
```

Answer (score 2):

Found solution.

Need to add following to node.conf:

```
    "cordappSignerKeyFingerprintBlacklist" : [
],
```

due to this occurring during attempted loading of "demo" apps:

`[WARN ] 2019-10-15T18:30:02,203Z [main] cordapp.JarScanningCordappLoader.loadCordapps - Not loading CorDapp Corda Finance Demo (R3) as it is signed by development key(s) only: [Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 1606301601488985262456987828510069198490398827685577289418991162593641911319
  public y coord: 39305038020852387120148508817752828470229346772241518574141632445003972282481
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)].
[WARN ] 2019-10-15T18:30:02,217Z [main] cordapp.JarScanningCordappLoader.loadCordapps - Not loading CorDapp Corda Finance Demo (R3) as it is signed by development key(s) only: [Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 1606301601488985262456987828510069198490398827685577289418991162593641911319
  public y coord: 39305038020852387120148508817752828470229346772241518574141632445003972282481
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)].
[WARN ] 2019-10-15T18:30:02,232Z [main] cordapp.JarScanningCordappLoader.loadCordapps - Not loading CorDapp Corda Finance Demo (R3) as it is signed by development key(s) only: [Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 1606301601488985262456987828510069198490398827685577289418991162593641911319
  public y coord: 39305038020852387120148508817752828470229346772241518574141632445003972282481
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)].
[WARN ] 2019-10-15T18:30:02,332Z [main] cordapp.JarScanningCordappLoader.loadCordapps - Not loading CorDapp Corda Finance Demo (R3) as it is signed by development key(s) only: [Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 1606301601488985262456987828510069198490398827685577289418991162593641911319
  public y coord: 39305038020852387120148508817752828470229346772241518574141632445003972282481
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)].
[INFO ] 2019-10-15T18:30:02,871Z [main] internal.Node.startNode - The Corda node is running in production mode. If this is a developer environment you can set 'devMode=true' in the node.conf file.`